# Why are .java files generated when .cs should be in c#/Antlr4.Runtime.Standart?

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4, antlr4cs

I need to write a translator for the language. I decided to use ANTLR4.
The files for the parser are generated for Java, but I need them to be generated for C#. What do I need to add or do to change the language for which files will be created?

According to the documentation, I installed the Nuget package Antlr4.Runtime.Standart, and also installed the extension in VS Code. Then I downloaded the latest jdk.
I created a project, added a *.g4 file, wrote a grammar, saved the file and everything worked. BUT! *.java files were generated, but should be *.cs. What did I forget to configure? What needs to be specified so that files are generated for C# and not for Java?
[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKlv4.png)
Here is the code in the .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr4.Runtime.Standard" Version="4.13.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I assume you are using [this extension](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/)? Did you set the language in your VSCode settings? You should set the language to "CSharp".

Comment: There are two parts to Antlr: the "tool" (which is a Java program), and the "runtime" (which is written for a specific target language, like CSharp). You need to run the tool with the option `-Dlanguage=CSharp`. You can set that up in VSCode with the Antlr extension by Mike. But, generating the parser and lexer manually is a terrible idea. You should use an integrated build solution that does this for you. See [Antlr4BuildTasks](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks). Just set up the `<ItemGroup>` for Antlr4BuildTasks in your csproj file, then "build". Do not use "antlr4cs"!!

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/how-to-use-antlr-4-on-net-in-2023/ You missed the actual grammar to C# compilation step.

Comment: @kaby76 Hello, thank you for your answer to my question! I set the necessary settings in the VS Code extension and everything worked, but I will definitely look at Antlr4BuildTasks. Can you also please share the best practices on Antlr4+.NET If there are any?